# (nil) pointer in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, pointers, printing, format-specifiers

I am working on a project and I keep coming across this error that will not allow me to complete the project. When I initialize one of my pointers to point to an object that will be made during the execution of the program and I initialize it to `NULL`. Then when I check to see what it is set to it returns a value of `nil`. How is such a thing possible? I didn't believe that nil pointers existed in C. Is there any way around this?

```
struct order_line *front = NULL;
...
printf("Head: %p\n", front);  // prints -> Head: (nil)
```

Comment: How do you check your pointer value ? Debugguer ? Printf ? This may just be a problem of representing the NULL pointer by your tool.

Comment: What does "nil" mean here? 0? Objective-C?

Comment: I am using printf(%p) to check it and it is in regular C not objective

Comment: can you post some sample code with which the problem is reproducible?

Comment: @Chris NULL pointers is an integral feature of C, and some system will just print a NULL pointer as "nil" when you use the `%p` conversion specifier. Post some code that shows the error.

Comment: Could you explain if nil is the output of printf, an runtime error message, a message you got at compile time ? In the first case, I think it is normal.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`%p` in `printf` formats a pointer type. This is going to distinguish a null-pointer and print `(nil)` because it is a special value in the context of a pointer. If you want to output 0 for a null pointer, cast the pointer to an integer and use `%d` instead:

```
printf("Head: %d\n", (int) front);
```

Original answer as it may still be useful:

`NULL` is a macro defined as `0` or `((void *) 0)`, so if you set a pointer to `NULL` it's exactly the same as setting it to `0`. This works for the purposed of declaring null pointers because the memory at address 0 will never be allocated to your program.

Comment: 'nil' does not exist in C unless you defined it.

Comment: struct order_line *front = NULL;
    ...
    printf("Head: %p\n", front);

Comment: In C, `NULL` may be defined as `((void *) 0)`

Comment: @Chris But does that line result in `nil`?

Comment: I added some of the code in. The printf is what ends up giving me a (nil)

Comment: I figured it out we were given a pointer which had not had memory allocated to it at first instead it was just defined.

Answer (score 5):

use

```
printf("Head: %s, %d, %p\n", front, front, front);
```

to print `Head: (null), 0, (nil)`

Thanks
Packia

Answer (score 3):

When you print a pointer using `printf("%p", somePtr)`, it is printed in an *implementation-defined manner*, as per this quote from the [POSIX printf specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/fprintf.html) (similar wording exists in the C99 specification also).

> The argument must be a pointer to void. The value of the pointer is converted to a sequence of printable characters, in an implementation-dependent manner.

I guess, that this means if the pointer is `NULL`, it may print it however it wants, including printing it as `nil` or `0x00000000` or `0`.

Comment: well I only ever end up getting (nil) but is there any way to get around this problem because my checks for NULL are not catching this and it continues to seg fault my program

Comment: @Chris: Convert it to an integer type and print it as an integer rather than a pointer (this is also an implementation-defined behaviour but is usually well-supported). The `uintptr_t` type defined in `<stdint.h>` should help you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that nil is what your debugger is telling you.  In most compilers null is just #define ed to 0 anyway so that name is not that important.

Comment: I am running a check within it to check for NULL but when I check what it is pointing to I get (nil).

Comment: typedef to 0? That isn't any typedef I've ever heard of. :p

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, there is no such thing as nil pointer in C.

May be your memory allocation fails, causing `0` to be assigned to the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about comparing the pointer value to NULL then the value printed by printf() shouldn't matter. You can still do **if(ptr==NULL)** for that.

  ptr = (nil) and NULL = (nil) => ptr = NULL :)

The error you are getting must because of some other reason.

Answer (score 0):

After casting the structure pointer with int ,  it provides the expected condition with if statement ..

```
printf("The address of the variable is---ps->p---After Deletion-- %p \n",ps->p);
printf("The address of the variable is---ps->p---After Deletion--  %d \n",(int)ps->p);
if((int)ps->p){
printf("Again in Free\n");
doFree((void **)&ps->p);
}
```

OUTPUT :-

The address of the variable is---ps->p---After Deletion-- nil
The address of the variable is---ps->p---After Deletion-- 0

it will evaluates to false for if condition .